# Is there any issues using this? <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, meta-tags

I just discovered this line of code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

which makes all IE behave like IE9.

I was surprised that  I did not know about that before.

Does it work perfectly? or does it have problems?
and if it does work perfectly, why are we struggling with IE6 - IE7 - IE8 when this exist?

Comment: That doesn't force *all* IEs to behave like IE9, merely IE9 and future versions. IE6/7/8 will not magically switch to IE9 behavior.

Comment: But some css3 features that work on IE9, work on IE7/IE8 if I use this code, so what happens exactly?!

Answer (score 0):

That line of code caused my site to briefly load and then gave me a 404 error.  I deleted it and it works fine now.

Comment: That's not very helpful. The OP asked about the details of this meta tag. You should at least describe your environment (browser, version, web server etc.) and a more detailed error message, so that one can investigate the behaviour further.